# Date-time picker is not showing on safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, safari

I have to give input to select date and time. I'm using input type as "datetime-local". It is working as expected on other then safari browser.

My input code is as below:

```
<input class="form-control" name="expire_at" type="datetime-local" id="example-datetime-local-input" required>
```

[image: Safari Image]

Expected input:

[image: Expected Input]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version you are using? Safari version 14 and below is not compatible with type=“datetime-local” you can check all the list here https://caniuse.com/?search=datetime-local

Comment: is there any alternate solution possible ?